# Unable to refresh a tab on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am  trying to refresh a tab on click of a button.But i get an error "Undefined is not a function".

Below is the html code

```
 <div class="tabbable" id ="tabs">  
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">  
  <li class="active"><a href="#overview" >Overview</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#edit" >Edit Company</a></li>  
  <li class=""><a href="#site" class ="site">Add/Manage Sites</a></li>    
  <li class=""><a href="#user" >Manage Users</a></li> 
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="site">  
    <div class="container center">
        <h3 class="center">Sites Management</h3>
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="table-manage-user">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Site Name</label></td
                <td><label>Action</label></td>
            </tr>
            </thead>

         <tr>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control name"   id="site_name{ID}" value="{NAME}">    </td>

<td><div class="btn-group form-actions">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Action <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#" class='deleteSite' id='{ID}'>Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div></td>
</tr>

        </table>
    </div>        
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.deleteSite').on( 'click', function( event ) {
   $('#tabs').tabs('load', 2);

});
```

can anyone tell me what's wrong in here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you check if the necessary `jQuery` libraries are loaded? If so, is the `tabs` plugin initiated?

Comment: @MelanciaUK: yes. it is